# URLSessionWebSocketTask not being released after invalidate session

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket, urlsession

I have this class for handling WebSocket communication.

```
final class SocketService: NSObject, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {

    private var session: URLSession?
    private var socketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
    private var request: URLRequest?

    init(_ configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, _ url: URL) {
        super.init()
        self.request = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        self.socketTask = self.session?.webSocketTask(with: self.request!)
        self.socketTask?.resume()
    }

    public func cleanup() {
        self.session?.invalidateAndCancel()
        self.session = nil
        
        self.socketTask?.cancel()
        self.socketTask = nil
    }

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) { }

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) { }
```

After a I run the func `cleanup()` even though the class `SocketService` gets `deinit` I see in the memory debugger that the session itself and the `__NSURLSessionWebSocketTask` are still allocated under `CFNetwork` and when created a new instance of the class it creates even more `__NSURLSessionWebSocketTask` instances.

Here is a screenshot of the memory debug :

[image]

Running on an actual device iOS 15.7 iPhone 6s.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.